# Lightning event.getSource() is returning different data structures for same input types in 2 almost identical components. Why is that the case?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

Component 1

HTML:

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="Contact.LastName" value="{!v.contact.LastName}" change="{!c.handleInputChange}"/>
```

Controller:

```
handleInputChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var m = helper.getLeadContactMappingFromClickEvent(event);
    var button = component.find('adopt-Lead.' + m.leadFieldName + '-button');
    button.set('v.iconName', 'action:close');
    helper.fireContactFieldsChangedEvent(component);
}
```

Helper:

```
// example of mapping string: 'Lead.Salutation:Contact.Salutation'
// is meant to be located on tr parent element of currently changing input
getLeadContactMappingFromClickEvent: function(event) {
    // goes up in DOM hierarchy and retrieves id of tr element
    // the id contains mapping between Lead field
    console.log('contact change event source', event.getSource());
    var mappingString = event.getSource().elements[0].parentElement.parentElement.id;
    var split = mappingString.split(':');
    return {
        leadFieldName: split[0].replace('Lead.', ''),
        contactFieldName: split[1].replace('Contact.', '')
    };
}
```

Results of `console.log('contact change event source', event.getSource());`

[image]

---

Component 2

HTML:

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="Account.Name" value="{!v.account.Name}" change="{!c.handleInputChange}"/>
```

Controller:

```
handleInputChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    var m = helper.getLeadAccountMappingFromClickEvent(event);
    var button = component.find('adopt-Lead.' + m.leadFieldName + '-button');
    if (button) {
        button.set('v.iconName', 'action:close');
    }
    helper.fireAccountFieldsChangedEvent(component);
}
```

Helper:

```
getLeadAccountMappingFromClickEvent: function(event) {
    console.log('account change event source', event.getSource());
    var mappingString = event.getSource().elements[0].parentElement.parentElement.id;
    var split = mappingString.split(':');
    return split.length > 1
        ? {
            leadFieldName: split[0].replace('Lead.', ''),
            accountFieldName: split[1].replace('Account.', '')
        }
        : {
            leadFieldName: null,
            accountFieldName: split[0].replace('Account.', '')
        };
}
```

Results of `console.log('account change event source', event.getSource());`

[image]

I'm trying to get the same `event.getSource()` data structure for 'Component 2' as I'm getting for 'Component 1'.

Comment: are they in two different org?

Comment: Same org. They are used in same wizard and are rendered dynamically with `$A.createComponent(componentName, ...`, depending on step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: This is due to different API Versions. Contact component is below API 40.0. The Account component is API v40 - which means the Account component gets Event Data as defined by the Locker Service.

To maintain functionality, either downgrade or rebuild Account cmp Locker Service compliant.

Comment: You are right, thank you. The Contact component bundle is API v38.0, Account: v40.0. I'm experimenting with a different solution rather than trying to get `.parentElement.parentElement`. I think I can achieve similar results with simple event bubbling